# comparing two arrays of bolean

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array(['numeric','string','numeric'])
b = np.array(['numeric','string','numeric','numeric','string'])
```

I am trying to compare two arrays a and b.

I want to get something like  : `array([ True,  True,  True])` because the 3 first elements are identical.

I know i could potentially truncate the biggest array in order to compare them :

```
if len(a)-len(b)<0:
    b = np.array(b[0:len(a)-len(b)])

if len(a)-len(b) > 0:
    a = np.array(a[0:len(b)-len(a)])  

b==a
```

or

```
if len(a)-len(b)<0:
    b = b[0:len(a)]
else:
    a = a[0:len(b)]
a==b
```

but i'm wondering if there are a built in numpy function to do this without having to truncate them.

Comment: Use `min_length = min(len(a), len(b))`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think  he needs to compute `min_len = min(len(a), len(b))` and then compare using `b[0:min_len] == a[0:min_len]`.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh of course!

Comment: Not sure if truncate is right word, do you mean slicing? Computationally, slicing the array will be the best option here since it will return a view of the original array.

Comment: i meant slicing you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built in function for this, I'm not sure, but here's a quick solution:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['numeric','string','numeric'])
b = np.array(['numeric','string','numeric','numeric','string'])
c = np.array([i == j for i, j in zip(a, b)])
print(c)
```

```
Out: [True,  True,  True]
```

Zip will automatically truncate the longer array to match the length of the shorter array.

A word of caution though, this is a solution for a List or a 1D array.  If you plan to do this with a 2D array, a different solution will be needed.